# View Files In The popup

Tags: laravel, file, amazon-s3, storage, drive

I am creating a project similar to **Google Drive** and storing my files on **S3**.
The problem is after upload of files i want it to be viewed in the same popup so that the link is not displayed and user can view the file.
I got my hands with **viewerJs** but it didn't worked well.

Which other option is better?

Comment: Do you want to display it after the upload or even before the upload?

Comment: after the upload... i dont want the s3 url to be seen to the user